# OkHttp/Android does not returns full results

Tags: android, okhttp

I have the following code, which expected to return the whole html file content loaded from http://developer.android.com .

(code is in Xtend but I think it doesn't matter).

```
var html = try {
        var client = new OkHttpClient()
        var request = new Request.Builder()
                        .url("http://developer.android.com/")
                        .build()
        var response = client.newCall(request).execute()

        response.body.string
    } catch(IOException err) {
        e("HTML error", err.toString)
        return
    }

    Log.d("HTML", html)
```

The output got cut off after a few lines of html.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>




<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0,minimum-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1.0,user-scalable=no">
<meta content="IE=edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
<meta name="description" content="The official site for Android developers. Provides the Android SDK and documentation for app developers and designers.">
<meta name="xsrf_token" content="A3XCSylWU7AR4OhsL_yhMWlzbNcbh9Hk3Csw0HAUa5E6MTQ2NDQyMTgwNzE1MDQ0MA" />

<link rel="alternate" href="http://developer.android.com/index.html" hreflang="en">
<link rel="alternate" href="http://developer.android.com/index.html?hl=es" hreflang="es">
<link rel="alternate" href="http://developer.android.com/index.html?hl=id" hreflang="id">
<link rel="alternate" href="http://developer.android.com/index.html?hl=ja" hreflang="ja">
<link rel="alternate" href="http://developer.android.com/index.html?hl=ko" hreflang="ko">
<link rel="alternate" href="http://developer.android.com/index.html?hl=pt-br" hreflang="pt-br">
<link rel="alternate" href="http://developer.android.com/index.html?hl=ru" hreflang="ru">
<link rel="alternate" href="http://developer.android.com/index.html?hl=vi" hreflang="vi">
<link rel="alternate" href="http://developer.android.com/index.html?hl=zh-cn" hreflang="zh-cn">
<link rel="alternate" href="http://developer.android.com/index.html?hl=zh-tw" hreflang="zh-tw">

<title>

  Android Developers

</title>

<!-- STYLESHEETS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed">
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:light,regular,medium,thin,italic,mediumitalic,bold"
    title="roboto">





<link href="/static/css/default.css?v=2016052807" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<!-- JAVASCRIPT -->
<script src="//www.google.com/jsapi" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://developer.android.com/_static/23ecca3dc9/js/android_3p-bundle.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
  var toRoot = '/';
  var metaTags = ""; 
  var devsite = true;
  var useUpdatedTemplates = true;
  var devsiteLang = 'en';
  var pageType = 'none';
  var ANDROID_LANGUAGES = [


      'en','es','in','ja','ko','pt-br','ru','vi','zh-cn','zh-tw'

  ];
</script>
<script src="/static/js/docs.js?v=2016052807" type="text/javascript"></script>


<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
  ga('create', 'UA-5831155-1', 'android.com');
  ga('create', 'UA-49880327-2', 'android.com', {'name': 'universal'});  // New tracker);
  ga('send', 'pageview');
  ga('universal.send', 'pageview'); // Send page view for new tracker.
</script>


</head>

<body class="gc-documentation none None full-width" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Article">
  <a href="#top" id="skip-to-main">Skip to content</a>
  <header id="header-wrapper">
    <div class="dac-header" id="header">
      <div class="dac-header-inner">
        <a class="dac-nav-toggle" data-dac-toggle-nav href="" title="Open navigation">
          <span class="dac-nav-hamburger">
            <span class="dac-nav-hamburger-top"></span>
            <span class="dac-nav-hamburger-mid"></span>
            <span class="dac-nav-hamburger-bot"></span>
          </span>
        </a>

        <a class="dac-header-logo" href="https://developer.android.com/index.html">
          <img class="dac-header-logo-image" src="https://developer.android.com/static/images/android_logo.png"
              srcset="https://developer.android.com/static/images/android_logo_2x.png 2x"
              width="32" height="36" alt="Android"> Developers</a>
        <ul class="dac-header-tabs">
          <li>
            <a class="dac-header
```

I have tried using `UrlConnection` as well but the result is not different. This is tested on the actual device (Samsung Galaxy Note 10.1 running unofficial Cyanogen Mod) and the AVD (Atom x64 with Android 6.0).

I have also tried with a handful of url and the results is quite the same (the response get cut off somewhere).

I don't really know what should I do next. Can you please suggest ?

Answer (score 1):

some of data is loaded with javaScript after page is actually loaded in browser ) download javaScripts and analyse them )

Comment: Well yes some are AJAX and would require JS to load them dynamically afterward. However in my case it does not even download the page fully (and there's no errors whatsoever).

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```java
public static String readResponseBody(Response response) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(response.body().charStream());;
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    while (true) {
        String line = reader.readLine();
        if (line == null)
            break;
        stringBuilder.append(line);
    }
    return stringBuilder.toString();
}
```

Comment: The results is pretty much the same.

Comment: The result can't be the same. Make sure you don't call response.body.string.
You should call readResponseBody(response) instead

Comment: Well as my answer below, I find that the the function actually return full body, but the ADB does not print out the full results so I thought it was chopped off half way. 

Yes the results wouldn't be the same as this one does not put the line break into the string builder (thus it becomes a single line).

Answer (score 0):

Apologizes to every participant. It seems like the library/platform works as expected. The problem probably lies in the DDMS.

I've tried reading the whole html and then get the last few characters display on the DDMS (using Log class) and turns out it's the closing tag of html `</html>`. I'm pretty sure the results return as a whole.

But if I put the whole string into log functions then it get chopped off around 4000th characters. Probably the adb buffer limits or something.